# wtelegramclient - how get event of added new comments for message

Tags: c#, wtelegramclient

I am using follow code:

```
_clientTelegram.OnUpdate += ListenUpdate;
```

And `Handler` of listener updates:

```
private async Task ListenUpdate(IObject arg)
{
    if (arg is not UpdatesBase updates)
    {
        _logger.LogWarning($"received not UpdatesBase event: {arg.GetType()}");
        return;
    }
    foreach (var update in updates.UpdateList)
        switch (update)
        {
            case UpdateNewMessage unm: await ProcessEventMessage(unm.message); break;
            case UpdateEditMessage uem: await ProcessEventMessage(uem.message); break;
            default: _logger.LogInformation($"handle a type message type: {update.GetType().Name}"); break; 
        }
}
```

And what names of event, where I undersand that new comment added?

Or on every `UpdateEditMessage` I have to using  `await _clientTelegram.Messages_GetReplies(peerChanel, telegramMessageId, limit: MaxRowsComments)`  ?

Comment: Have you tried to ask this in [WTelegramClient](https://t.me/WTelegramClient) Telegram group?

Comment: No, I did not know about ones.

Comment: @KanekoQt I prefer people ask their question here rather than the Telegram group, it makes the answer public for other to beneficiate from it. Especially if the question is a general question about the Telegram API rather than a behavior specific to the library

Comment: @Wizou, then ask question here and send it to Telegram group for faster reply > profit)

Comment: @KanekoQt you do realize i'm the library author? please don't duplicate your questions on both sites, it waste my time..

Comment: @Wizou, I mean not to duplicate, but send link to question on stackoverflow to Tg chat

Answer (score 0):

Channel comments are simply messages posted in the discussion group associated with the channel.

So, the easiest solution would be to join the discussion group, and handle `UpdateNewMessage` for that group peer.

Comment: When I receive event `UpdateNewMessage` how do I undestatand this new message or new comment for message? I already get new messages for channel correct

Comment: You first need to check the Peer ID to determine if it's posted in Channel or in the discussion group.
Further, I recommend you to read the official documentation: https://corefork.telegram.org/api/discussion
and https://corefork.telegram.org/api/threads